# Implementing a Unix shell in C: Logging

Tags: command-line, shell, c, programming, system-programming

I am currently working on implementing my own UNIX shell in C. The basis of the shell is working, you could find [the source code here](https://github.com/rahmu/Agros).

Right now my next task is to implement a logging feature for the shell. So here's my question:

What are the UNIX/Linux best practices to do that? The simple way would be to open a file and write to it every time. But I was wondering if there is a function that would take care of that for me, helping me produce ... "cleaner"... code.

Thank you in advance for your help, I'm quite new to programming, but I want to do things right.

PS: If you have any general remarks about the rest of the code, they'd be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Logging as in the `script` command common in many shells or writing unusual conditions into `/var/log`, or what?

Comment: More like having a log of all the command entered in /var/log. I thought I was clear. Sorry.

Comment: Then syslog is all you need.

Comment: I liked your code. Clean, simple and well documented! (+1) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically command history is saved to a hidden file in the user's home directory. Other than that, you can log to stderr or [syslog](http://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog).

Answer (score 1):

Common practice for logging is to use syslog. It's quite simple and does not require much code.
If you need something else - look at logging libraries like [liblogging](http://www.liblogging.org/) or [log4c](http://log4c.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm going with syslog, since I don't need anything extravagant and don't want to include any extra dependency. Can you tell me if syslog() is available on other Unices like BSD or Solaris?

Comment: It's available on FreeBSD from libc.so and I'm 95% sure that Solaris has syslog() too.

Comment: I checked yesterday at work, it is indeed available on Solaris 10. Thanks!